# assets/appconfig.production.json not found angular azure

Tags: angular, azure, hosting

I'm running a simple SPA where back and front are hosted separately in Azure.
I have

```js
"assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/web.config",
              {
```

then my web.config looks like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    <!-- IIS URL Rewrite for Angular routes -->
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What I'm getting in the network tab is :
[Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwkXm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this is : go to Azure pipelines and configure Azure App Service Deploy.
Get into Additional Deployment Options -> Select deployment method -> Zip Deploy.

Tbh I have no idea why Web Deploy was ignoring web.config, but oh well.